# Password Hashing issue with password_hash & password_verify

Tags: php, passwords, php-5.5, php-password-hash

I currently upgraded my server to PHP 5.5 and want to make good use of the new functions `password_hash` and `password_verify`.

I cant seem to get a hash to be verified correctly? I have copied the exact examples from the PHP manual and it still seems to be returning `false`?

Is their something I am missing?

```
$hash = password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";


if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

returns

```
Invalid password.
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is localized and trivial.

Comment: @tereško i disagree, leave open. this could be a common problem if someone is misreading the documentation. trivial questions are on topic.

Comment: This is why you don't just blindly copy/paste code examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're appending a `\n` to your hash, which CHANGES the hash:

```
$hash = password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
                                                         ^^^^---here
```

Eliminate that, and it'll start working.

Comment: Yup, thats it! Why would they include that in the example?

Comment: Because they're doing an  `echo`, so they want a newline to pervent the next text output from smashing up against the hash.

Comment: @MarcB You kind of figure that php.net would have made a mention about that in their manual in regards to working with a database. I can't find anything on the web about this. Or, am I not digging deep enough? Even though it's intended for an echo, they should have added the fact that it adds an invisible linefeed to the hash which IMHO should have been included in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are appending a new line with `'\n'` at the end.

They are using that to add a newline to the output in the examples.

Comment: Perfect thank you! Why would they include that in the example?

Comment: @Trendee because they are `echo`ing the result.